# caculating the circuit by thevinin method

Tags: thevenin

can someone please solve the circuit from the image that i have posted as a photo file. I have to find the current through (100 ohm colored orange). I have to slove this with the method of thevenin. . I would be very grateful if someone can solve it.

I have to solve this with thevenin and not with norton. I dont know how to solve it from node voltage method because my teacher didnt taught this. So I did with the method called superposition method. I dont have the answer because this was one of my exam question. I tried this with norton but i get two different ansewer.  can some one check this for me

[image: Calculating with thevenin page 1 Superposition method]

[image: Calculating with thevenin page 2 Superposition method]

Comment: What "method of thevenin" do you mean? Thevenin's theorem only? No Norton? Or do you mean to include both? Do you have any thoughts at all about how you might redraw the above schematic to help you organize it better for a solution? I see no work at all, just a request for a solution. Which doesn't sound much like you want to *learn to fish*, but just want someone to *give you a fish*.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because homework without an attempt to a solution is off topic.

Comment: Sorry that i diddnt post my solved version. now i have posted it . I had to do this with superposition method and thevinin. this was one of my question from exam. So i dont have the answer. can you please check this for me if my answer is right.

Comment: @RoshanTimsina +1 for showing your work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by redrawing your schematics so that they conform to rules important for understanding them. You should get into the regular practice of redrawing any schematic when you don't understand it well.

Current flow should be arranged so that the top of a schematic is the most positive and the bottom of the schematic is the most negative (so far as you can tell, anyway.) Although not a strict rule, it often also helps to have current sources pointing downward so that they appear to be "going with the flow" from the top towards bottom of the sheet. Signal, if applicable, should flow from left to right, with inputs on the left and outputs on the right.

Don't bus voltage rails (or ground) around. You don't need to see all the connections as it doesn't matter (mostly) for understanding a circuit. I've eliminated the useless wiring you added. Just label the nodes where you know the voltage.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fDtmXN.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The above schematic is the same. Go through each of the devices and nodes and I think you will see that they are equivalent.

At this point, you are supposed to use your brain. What do you know about current sources? In the above circuit, what impact or importance does \$R_6\$ have? How does it affect the rest of the circuit? Would anything change if you made its value larger, or smaller? What would happen to the circuit if you simply removed it by shorting it out? What would change, if so? (Look closely at what is happening at the connected nodes.)

---

EDIT: Thanks for adding your work. This much more fully explains what you meant when you wrote, earlier. Now let's go through your approach:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ftI8DV.png)</sup>

The left side is your "step 1" and the right side is your "step 2." You did get the right resistance value for "step 3." So let's look at the above two steps.

Note that with the current source in place and the voltage source shorted, you get \$V_A-V_B=+15\:\textrm{V}\$. And with the current source removed and the voltage source in place, there is no current anywhere so \$V_A-V_B=+20\:\textrm{V}\$. These sum to a magnitude of \$35\:\textrm{V}\$.

So the final current, using your computed \$R=275\:\Omega\$, is \$I=\frac{35\:\textrm{V}}{275\:\Omega}=\frac{7}{55}\:\textrm{A}\$.

Comment: thanks, but i did with another method because my teacher didnt taught me this method. Can u please see my method and say if the answer is correct or not. It will be helpful if u can only say the answer by calculating with your method so that i can see if i am right or not. This was one of my question from my exam and i had to do this with superposition method and thevenin. I tried this with norton but the circuit is not efficient as from thevenin.

Comment: @RoshanTimsina You got the resistance calculation correct. But you should find that it is \$35\:\textrm{V}\$ across it.

Comment: @RoshanTimsina This is the sum of \$20\:\textrm{V}\$ with the current source removed and \$15\:\textrm{V}\$ with the voltage source removed. I think a mistake you made is in the sign of a voltage across one of the resistors when the current source is active and the voltage source removed, as well as not knowing what to do with the current source removed.

Comment: @RoshanTimsina See the new additions I made to my answer.

Comment: Thank you so much  for giving me your time. I understand now. Sorry for asking u too much  but i want to ask you one one more question. That traingle shaped what are those and how you know where it can be placed.

Comment: @RoshanTimsina That's called a "ground reference." It only means that I mentally decided that the node attached to it is \$0\:\textrm{V}\$ for purposes of reference for any other voltages that are mentioned in the circuit.

Comment: @RoshanTimsina If this is an answer for you, you may as well mark it as answered. This provides you with some points but also helps others avoid the question of whether or not they should spend their time adding an answer. (If you want more thoughts, then keep it open. But if not, it is better to close it.)